# How do I completely remove geckodriver?

Tags: firefox

I have tried removing the files and uninstalling Firefox but when I do a version check for it in terminal, it still lists it.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

- `whereis geckodriver`   to find the location(s)
- `sudo rm <location_from_previous_command>`

Answer (score -1):

### Using `apt` from command line. Just use the command

```
sudo apt-get remove package_name
```

If you want to also remove user data and configuration files

```
sudo apt-get purge package_name
```

Using `--auto-remove` parameter will also remove package dependencies.

### Using `dpkg` from command line

Just use the command

```
sudo dpkg -r package_name
```

To remove a package and its configuration files

```
sudo dpkg -P package_name
```

Files in your home folder are not part of the package so they will stay on your system until you remove them by yourself.

Comment: first one: E: Unable to locate package geckodriver
second one: E: Unable to locate package geckodriver
third: dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove geckodriver which isn't installed
fourth: dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove geckodriver which isn't installed. But when i type geckodriver --version I get geckodriver 0.20.1

Comment: This would be a good guide for generally removing packages (though surely marking as a duplicate would be a better move if a general guide is what @DMellon asked for). This does *not* help for a case like `geckodriver`, as the OP mentioned in the comment above.